# How to run spring batch job in multiple threads at the same time

Tags: spring-batch

I have a spring batch job with the following definition :

```
    <batch:step id="step1">
        <batch:tasklet task-executor="simpleTaskExecutor">
            <batch:chunk reader="itemReader" processor="itemProcessor"
                writer="itemWriter" >
            </batch:chunk>
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
    <bean id="itemReader" class="CustomReader">
</bean>
```

Custom reader , reads a row from database and pass it to processor for further processing.

My problem is i want to have multiple threads at the same time to run this job at the same time ( each read a row and process)  . based on documentation i used taskExecutor but it didn't worked.

note : my scenario doesn't fit with partitioner.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "doesn't" work?

If you want to read and process one entry with each thread, you need to have a "commit-interval" of exactly one. (http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html)

But note: since several threads will call the reader and writer (they are singleton instances) in parallel you have to ensure that both are thread-safe. The simplest thing to do this would be to synchronize the read, resp. the write method of the reader and writer.